# Wordpress Custom Post Type "Read More" problem

Tags: wordpress

I've created a custom post type made with [this tutorial](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type/). The problem is when I try to display a part of the post it works exact the opposite way!

Post text:

```
You should see me!
<!--more-->
Not me. At least not yet.
```

PHP code:

```
<?php the_content("Read more...",TRUE,''); ?>
```

Should display something like:

"You should see me!

Read more..."

But it displays:

"Not me. AT least not yet."

And no "Read more..." link.

What's going on?

Comment: You might be better off asking this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, btw.

Comment: I agree...or at wordpress.org forums. However, we may be able to help here. Can you post your entire loop? Try resettings `$more` similar to `<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); global $more; $more = 0; if (have_posts()) : ?>` Also, try `the_content()` without the other stuff in there, like `the_content('Read more...');`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having same problem. After a detailed observation I found that read more tag doesn't work on template tags. See here

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

The  quicktag will not operate and is ignored in Templates where just one post is displayed, such as single.php.